# 865 vs 997 Acknowledgement file

Tags: edi, x12

May i use 997 acknowledgement file in place of 865 acknowledgement
 file for clients **in respect of receive 860 file not 850 file**. I think that is dependent on cutomer what they want.

```
What are differences between 865 and 997 Acknowledgement ?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The 997 is just confirmation (receipt) of the interchange (or group of documents).  This is a STANDARD document that allows you to determine delivery.  This was put in place before the communication protocols were robust enough to tell if a transmission failed (think bisynchronous modems).  So for every group of documents you send in an interchange, you should receive a 997.  You should be able to write reports on which groups / interchanges have not been acknowledged as received.  If you receive a document, you should send the 997 back.

The 865 is a BUSINESS document.  It is far more detailed.  Plus the 865 is the RESPONSE to the 860 document.  Just like the 855 is the response to the 850.

If you receive an 850, you send a 997. Then you would ALSO send the 855 (if partner requires).
If you receive the 860 (changing the initial PO), you would send the 997 confirming receipt.  You would ALSO send the 865.

Translators handle the 997.  Rarely do they get integrated in the ERP.  The 855/865 would get integrated, as business decisions get made from them.

Comment: I need to send confirmation that we received 860 file then i have simple query what acknowledgement (865 or 997) should be sent to customer for 860 (PO change file)?

Comment: You would send the 997 to confirm you received the 860. You should send a 997 for EVERY EDI document you receive.  If your customer wants you to send the 865, you would send that in addition to the 997.  Look at my 3rd paragraph for the life cycle.

Answer (score 4):

The 997 only serves as a receipt that the transmission was received, not that it was accepted. [Source](http://www.1edisource.com/learn-about-edi/transaction-sets/tset/997#axzz2hQF0SN7m).

Whereas the 865 is used to acknowledge that you accept (or reject) the changes to the purchase order. [Source](http://www.covalentworks.com/edi-865-purchase-order-change-acknowledgment.asp)

The difference is that if you just send a 997 instead of the 865, you are simply telling your partner that you received the transmission. You are not giving them any indication on whether or not you can meet requirements of the change. You would need to talk to your partner on whether this is acceptable or not and what their expectations are in the case that you can not meet the changes.

Comment: I got a case today where the customer did not fill in the "ship to" part of a 850, which turned out to prevent us from properly importing the PO inside our system. We do not send 865 here and I wondered if it was appropriate to return a 997 with the "Rejected" status. If 997's purpose is to acknowledge reception of the document, my feeling is that the answer's no. Am I correct?

Comment: @Crono The 865 is used for accepting/rejecting *changes*. The [855](http://www.1edisource.com/transaction-sets?TSet=855) is used to accecpt/reject the initial order. Your system should have responded with the 855. An [865](http://www.1edisource.com/transaction-sets?TSet=865) is relevant after an order has been confirmed and then a change was requested. In that case, the order of transactions would have been 850->855->860->865

Comment: We aren't sending 855 either, customer server won't take those. All we send back is 997.

Comment: If you are only using the 997, then I would assume that receiving rejection on the 997 means there is a syntax error (as you have described with the missing ship to address), but if you haven't encountered this before it's probably best to clarify that with the customer. They may not have the capability to handle rejections.